# Tomcat 9 shutdown did not work on windows and linux

Tags: tomcat, shutdown, tomcat9

Tomcat 9.0.12 shutdown did not work on windows and linux

```
bin\shutdown.bat  (win)
bin/shutdown.sh  (linux)
```

The commands run to complete without error, but the tomcat process(java) was not terminated.

Comment: On Linux, if you kill the process and restart, does the next shutdown work ?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely one of the web applications has started a background thread on its own, and is not shutting it down properly. A hacky alternative is to make background threads a daemon thread (there's a flag when starting the thread), which means that they'll be yanked whenever the process terminates.

Take a thread dump of the process (on Linux: `kill -3 pid`, then inspect catalina.out) and inspect the threads that are still running. Then locate the non-daemon threads in your code or your third party web applications and get rid of them.